# Sinatra on Rack under Passenger returning 0-byte pages

Tags: ruby, sinatra, passenger, rack

I'm trying to write a Sinatra app that will run on a shared Passenger server.  For now, I'd be happy just getting a "hello world", but something isn't working quite right.  I have:

config.ru

```
require 'vendor/sinatra-lib/sinatra.rb'
set :environment, :production
disable :run

require 'myapp.rb'
run Sinatra::Application
```

myapp.rb

```
get '/' do
  "Hello world!"
end
```

and of course all the support libs I need for sinatra are under /vendor/sinatra-lib.  I can rackup this exact load on my local machine, and it runs like a champ.  However, on the remote machine, I get 0-byte responses for any URL I try to visit.  Note that I have a /public directory, and I can view pages out of that successfully, so I guess Rack is still responding.  Also, I can run a basic Rack app without any problems, so Rack must be configured correctly (at least, correctly for running Rack apps).

At this point, the only thing I can think of is to check the version of Rack, etc, on the remote server.  I don't have full control over the box, so I don't really have log output to share.  I can try to chase it down, if it's important, but I'm hoping something will jump out at somebody.

Comment: Follow up: I *think* the server turns out to be running an old version of Rack (Rack::VERSION reports 0.10!  Is that even possible?) so I'm going to see if I can get it upgraded.

Comment: (As an aside, it would be nice if Sinatra could check its dependencies and die gracefully if they're not met)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for playing, turned out to be a dependency issue -- the server I was deployed to was running a version of Rack that was too old to support Sinatra.  Lots of good other stuff to think about, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the other sinatra files isn't in the load dir. Try to rename `vendor/sinatra-lib` into `vendor/sinatra`, and if it still doesn't work, try to add this in the top of your `config.ru`, in stead of `require 'vendor/...'`

```
$: << 'vendor/sinatra'
require 'sinatra'
```

A little side note: You are not required to pass the file extension (.rb) to `require`, so you could do `require 'myapp'` instead of `require 'myapp.rb'`.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and get back to you.  Thanks!